# Selecting the number of threads dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to create several threads based on the value received by the program.
I am using the following code.

```
int count = 7;
Class1 cl=new Class1();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs argss)
    {
        BackgroundWorker b = o as BackgroundWorker;
        cl.print("id","password");
    });
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

In print() method of class1 I print a single line "Just entered print function".

But when I run the program no line is printed.

Comment: I don't see how the question's title and content are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the background thread.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int count = 7;

            Class1 cl = new Class1();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
                bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
                delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs argss)
                {
                    BackgroundWorker b = o as BackgroundWorker;

                    cl.Print("id", "password");
                });

                bw.RunWorkerAsync();//Start the background here

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Class1
    {
        public void Print(string id, string password)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id:{0},Password:{1}", id, password);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN documentation of the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, you need to start it by calling, for example, [`RunWorkerAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Remember to check the documentation first before asking here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 4.5 you can save yourself some key strokes and use the TPL

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    Task.Run(() => cl.Print("id","password"));      
}
```